# Append doesn't work when writing to CSV in R

Tags: r

I have the following R script:

```
target <- c("Autocorrelation","InformationContent_zero","InformationContent_one","InformationContent_two",
            "InformationContent_four","PartialIC_zero","PartialIC_one","PartialIC_two","PartialIC_four",
            "DBI_zero","DBI_one","DBI_two","DBI_four")

for (tar in target){
  AC_data <- subset(data, select=c(tar))
  AC <- aggregate(AC_data , list(class=data$TARGET_CLASS), mean)
  ordered_AC <- AC[order(-AC[tar]),]
  write.csv(ordered_AC,file="/home/nasser/Desktop/Experiments/evosuite-report/finalData.csv",append=TRUE)
}
```

When I run the script with the data that I process I get the following results:

```
                    class Autocorrelation
16    SomeExternalClass11      0.26582445
3     MoreMethodsModified      0.21295785
10  MultiPlateauxModified      0.19942221
1             DoublePeaks      0.19534564
                    class InformationContent_zero
2             MoreMethods              0.17936452
7              MultiPeaks              0.13527150
12 NeedleInHaystackNoParm              0.11714634
6    MultiMethodsModified              0.07180512
                    class InformationContent_one
2             MoreMethods             0.17936452
7              MultiPeaks             0.13527150
12 NeedleInHaystackNoParm             0.11714634
6    MultiMethodsModified             0.07180512
```

The problem is that the only data that is written to the CSV file is the last group which is `class InformationContent_one`

That means the first two groups are overwritten. Do you know how to fix this and let all the data are written to the CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idiomatic way in R would be to `rbind` your data frames and write once:

```
write.csv(
  do.call(rbind, lapply(target, function(tar) {
    AC_data <- subset(data, select = c(tar))
    AC <- aggregate(AC_data , list(class = data$TARGET_CLASS), mean)
    res <- AC[order(-AC[tar]),]
    res$var <- names(res)[2]
    names(res)[2] <- "value"
    res
  })),
  file = "/home/nasser/Desktop/Experiments/evosuite-report/finalData.csv"
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I received the following error: `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names`

Comment: Yes, that's indicative that the data frames cannot be simply "piled up" because of different column names.

Comment: @AdamAmin See my edit, I slightly modified the structure of your output so that it can be piled up. See if it meets your requirements

Answer (score 6):

In the help for `write.table`, it states:

> write.csv and write.csv2 provide convenience wrappers for writing CSV
>   files.
>
> ...
>
> These wrappers are deliberately inflexible: they are
>   designed to ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a
>   valid file. Attempts to change append, col.names, sep, dec or qmethod
>   are ignored, with a warning.

If you want to append, you need to use `write.table` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `write.table()` and save your file as `.txt`. R will append both the variables names and their values. You can remove the variables names from values using transformation functions such as `anti_join()` and `filter()` from dplyr.