# Delimiters while writing csv files in R

Tags: r, linux, csv, delimiter

How can I use `|`(pipe) as a delimiter while writing csv files in R?

When I try writing a data set into a file with `write.csv` with `sep = "|"`, it ignores the separator and writes the file simply as a comma separated file.

Also `write.csv2` also doesn't seem to cover the other variety of characters which could be used as a separator.

Is there a way to use other characters such as ^, $, ~, ¬ or |, as a delimiter while writing a csv file in R.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand that `.csv` means "comma-separated value" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values.

If you want to export with a separator using that characters you need another function.

For example, using `write.table`, and you'll be able to load this file with `R`, `Excel`,....

```
write.table(data, "data.txt", sep = "|")
data_load <- read.table("data.txt", sep = "|")
```

Feel free to use any character as separator.

Or you could force this plain text to be `.csv`

```
write.table(data, "data.csv", sep = "|")
data_load <- read.csv("data.csv", sep = "|")
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just a variation of the one I gave for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50179309/269476). They are similar, but I don't think the question itself is an exact duplicate, but they are both part of a bigger question (not yet asked).

In the help for `write.table`, it states:

> write.csv and write.csv2 provide convenience wrappers for writing CSV files.
>
> ...
>
> These wrappers are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file.
>   Attempts to change append, col.names, sep, dec or qmethod are ignored,
>   with a warning.

To set `sep` or another of these parameters you need to use `write.table` instead of `write.csv`.